# RangeError: Error #3609: Stream 0 does not have enough vertices

Tags: flash, stage3d

I am developing a rotating cube in 3D using stage3D.

I can see the result perfectly in Firefox but in Chrome I cannot se nothing. When I set:

```
context.enableErrorChecking = true;
```

I receive this callback from the browser

```
RangeError: Error #3609: Stream 0 does not have enough vertices
```

The number of vertices is fine though.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This means your index buffer has an index for a vertex that is not present in the vertex buffer.
You receive this error even if you don't draw with that index. This is very annoying and it looks like Stage3D bug.

Comment: As I'm using externally made buffers, it was pretty hard to find which shape is causing the problem = I had more indexes than vertices as you correctly mentioned. I agree that it's very annoying behavior, to report the error even when the invalid index is not used.